# Classe não serializável

Tags: java, primefaces, apache, aplicação-web, tomcat

Seguinte, estou estudando um projeto envolvendo javaWeb, com `jsf`+`primefaces`. Estou usando o `apache tomcat 7`. O problema está acontecendo ao iniciar o serviço do apache pra depois testar minha aplicação, no qual o erro que identifiquei foi o seguinte:

```
fev 25, 2016 2:42:56 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession writeObject
ADVERTÊNCIA: Cannot serialize session attribute contatoController for
session 707B3CF6A468012EFA4220B84449EB6B java.io.NotSerializableException: Bean.ContatoBean
```

A minha classe ContatoBean é a seguinte:

```
public class ContatoBean implements Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String cidade;
    private String uf;
    private String telefone;
    private String celular;
    private String email;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }

    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return celular;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.celular = celular;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Mesmo eu retirando o `implements serializable`, ele continua dando erro, alguém sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: Você tem um long **serialVersionUID** declarado? ou a annotation **@SuppressWarnings("serial")**??

Comment: Não tenho Thiago, precisaria colocar nessa classe?
No caso seria private long serialVersionUID = 1; ???

Comment: Um exemplo: **private static final long serialVersionUID = -1931519544424229043L;**

Answer (score 1):

Quando um objeto é serializado no Java, essa sequência de bytes, além de conter seus atributos de instância não transientes, carrega consigo um número que indentifica a “versão” da classe que foi usada durante o processo.

Esse é o chamado `serialVersionUID`, ou seja, o indentificador de versão de serialização de uma classe.

Esse número é utilizado para saber se o objeto que estamos recuperando é de uma versão “compatível” com a versão da classe que foi utilizada quando serializamos o objeto: em outras palavras, os arquivos `.class` não precisam ser necessariamente os mesmos para que o processo de serialização ocorra com sucesso.

**Exemplo:**

```
public class ContatoBean implements Serializable{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = -1931519544424229043L;

// seu código..
}
```

Comment: O problema é que não sei como descobrir esse serialVerisoUID correto :/

Comment: Você tentou colocar algum valor? tipo -1L??

Answer (score 1):

O nome da classe ser logado como `Bean.ContatoBean` sugere que ela é uma classe interna (*inner class*), isto é, `ContatoBean` está declarada dentro de `Bean`.

Suponho também que a classe externa possui um atributo do tipo `ContatoController`.

Por exemplo:

```
public class Bean {
    ContatoController  contatoController;
    ...
    public class ContatoBean {
        ...
    }
}
```

O problema de classes internas é que elas mantém uma referência implícita à classe mais externa, de forma que você pode acessar os atributos dela. O efeito colateral disso, no seu caso, é que o Java está tentando serializar a classe externa junto com a interna, por causa da referência implícita.

Existem duas formas de solucionar isso:

## 1. Classe interna estática

Simplesmente mude a classe interna para ser estática. Isso faz com que ela não possa acessar os atributos da classe externa, mas pelo menos você vai ter o resultado desejado.

A partir daí ela será uma classe como qualquer outra, acessível por outras classes sem que seja necessário ter uma instância da classe externa.

Exemplo:

```
public class Bean {
    ContatoController  contatoController;
    ...
    public static class ContatoBean {
        ...
    }
}
```

## 2. Externalizar a classe interna

Mova a classe interna para uma classe normal, num arquivo separado.

Eu recomendo essa abordagem quando se trabalha com frameworks como JSF ou Spring, os quais instanciam classes usando reflexão.

Embora eles funcionem com classes internas na maioria das vezes, sempre existem alguns casos onde não funciona bem, como esse em que você se deparou.

Isso ocorre porque classes internas funcionam um pouco diferente de uma classe normal. Alguns dos detalhes você já percebeu pelo que eu escrevi, como a referência interna e também o nome classe conter o nome da classe externa.

Comment: luiz, na frase *"O efeito colateral disso, no seu caso, é que o Java está tentando serializar a classe externa junto com a externa, por causa da referência implícita."*, não seria *"...a classe externa junto com a interna(...)"* ou inverso?

Comment: @DiegoF Exato. Obrigado.